# Random flipping of fourth bit in random characters when reading context.request.body in C# Aspnetcore middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-10, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a somewhat unusual problem. I have a middleware proxy class meant to intercept certain requests, grab out their body, manipulate the contents, forward the request to another server, and then return the result with some further manipulations. Most of this works just fine, except for grabbing out the body. As far as I can tell, when extracting out the body, the contents are mangled in a very specific way: **the fourth bit of a few seemingly-randomly chosen characters will rarely be flipped incorrectly.** This causes some very specific mistakes: a lowercase `l` becomes a `|`, a doublequote `"` becomes a `2`, a `,` becomes a `<`, an uppercase `T` becomes an uppercase `D`, etc.

You can see what I mean about the fourth bit here:

- `l` (`01101100`) becomes
- `|` (`01111100`)

Below is the function I'm using to extract the Request Body, taken from elsewhere. I believe it is appropriate for the version of Asp.NET I am using.

```cs
private static async Task<string> GetBodyAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    string body;
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
    {
        body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    return body;
}
```

I inspect the request when it leaves the browser, and it is all perfectly valid JSON. I don't think any of my other middleware could be affecting it, but here is what else I have in my `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Application"));
}

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseMiddleware<CorsMiddleware>();

app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

For reference, the bodies are about 500k characters, as a big JSON formatted string. Near as I can tell, I am using UTF-8 encoding both client and server. My first thought was some kind of encoding issue, but I can't see where that could be happening. I have not yet noticed any pattern in WHICH characters are being flipped, although it is not frequent. Probably less than a hundred characters have this happen in the 500k example I just looked at? And this does not happen on every request, just randomly on some of them (more likely to happen if I try to fire off multiple requests at once).

Just to clarify further, this does NOT happen on my local machine, but seems to only happen on the Test server. Here is some information on that server:

- AspNetCore: 5.0.12
- Dotnet: 5.0.400
- IIS: 10.0.14393.0
- OS: Windows Server 2016

The application is built and deployed via ADO (.NET Core 5.0.x) to its own Application Pool using .NET CLR Version v4.0.30319 in Integrated mode.

Does anyone have ANY idea what could possibly be causing this? Or ideas to mitigate the problem?

Comment: Broken memory module?

Comment: Bit flipping is usually caused by bad hardware or hardware drivers. Don't waste your time on the software side.

Comment: Other possible causes: Power fluctuations, high temperature because lack of proper cooling. And in some instances even cosmic radiation.

Comment: Will this problem occur in the local system? Or is the problem only in iis?

Comment: It's only on the remote server, and only in this narrow specific situation as far as I can tell. So that rules out the usual hardware failures. It's just when reading large HTTP requests. Can't replicate it ever in local setup.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.